# A nested batch script with for , if and reg query loops

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am working on a batch script which will query some registries on other windows computers. It is going to iterate through all of the live IP addresses and that too after checking if I get the TTL from 120 to 128. Another requirement is to first check if first registry query is successful on every machine. For example it will start from 192.168.1.1, ping it once.
Get the TTL value.
If TTL ranges from 120 to 128 then it is a windows system.
Now query first registry.
If the query was successful then proceed querying other 6 more registries and keep writing the results to a txt file.
The ping part I was able to get using following:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,254) do for /f "tokens=8 delims=^= " %%b in ('ping -n 1 192.168.1.%%a ^| find /I "TTL"') do echo 192.168.1.%%a -- Online , TTL: %%b
```

Now I need to add IF condition to it. But it doesn't show any output:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,254) do for /f "tokens=8 delims=^= " %%b in ('ping -n 1 192.168.1.%%a ^| find /I "TTL"') do if %%b==128 echo 192.168.1.%%a -- Online , TTL: %%b
```

Next I need to query following registry:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName /v computername 2>null >> query_result.txt
```

If it is success, query rest of the registries.
And this all process has to be repeated for all 254 IP addresses.
In a plain and slow working way I did it followingly (for example):

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,254) do (reg query \\192.168.1.%%i\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName /v computername >> result.txt & reg query \\192.168.1.%%i\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion /v productname 2>null >> result.txt)
```

Although above code also works, but it is extremely slow, becoz it tries to query registry on dead IP addresses also. I had been following the three methods seperately in pieces using 3 result files. I want to club them.
How can I add all of them together? Plz clarify the application of IF conditional statements, on how to use them. I've been trying for 2 days but no success.

Thanks
marc_kriss

Answer (score 1):

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,254) do for /f "tokens=8 delims=^= " %%b in ('ping -n 1 192.168.1.%%a ^| find /I "TTL"') do if %%b==128 echo 192.168.1.%%a -- Online , TTL: %%b
```

Close, but it will only output if `%%b` is exactly 128. If you want `%%b` in the range `120 to 128`, then you'd need

```
... do if %%b leq 128 if %%b geq 120 echo ...
```

where `leq` means less than or equal to. I'll let you guess what `geq` means...

Instead of the `echo` here, you could naturally use

```
... geq 120 (
  echo processing 192.168.1.%%a onine TTL %%b
req query...192.168.1.%%a ...
)
```

to perform the reg query using the selected on-line machine addreses.

---

Response to comment:

On my machine, I found

```
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

Since you didn't post a sample filtered-ping result either, I have to use this data.

Now in the first result, `128` appears as %%b`

In the second, `TTL` appears since there's a `=` as `time`, not `<`. So tokens would need to be 9 not 8.

Or you could assign the entire string to an environment variable `yourstring` in `delayedexpansion` mode and then use

```
set "yourstring=!yourstring:*TTL=!"
set "yourstring=!yourstring:~1!"
```

Then you'd need to compare `!yourstring!` to 120,128 instead of `%%b`.

---

Revision

```dos
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for %%a in (192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3 127.0.0.1) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ('ping -n 1 %%a ^| find /I "TTL"') do (
 ECHO TTL line found FOR %%a is %%b
 set "yourstring=%%b" 
 set "yourstring=!yourstring:*TTL=!" 
 set "yourstring=!yourstring:~1!"
 ECHO yourstring is "!yourstring!"
 if !yourstring! leq 128 if !yourstring! GEQ 65 (
  echo %%a online , TTL: !yourstring!
  ECHO now DO whatever with "%%a" or "!yourstring!"
  reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName /v computername 2>nul 
 )
 ECHO end report FOR %%a ===============================
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Results on my machine:

```
TTL line found FOR 192.168.0.1 is Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
yourstring is "64"
end report FOR 192.168.0.1 ===============================
TTL line found FOR 192.168.0.2 is Reply from 192.168.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
yourstring is "128"
192.168.0.2 online , TTL: 128
now DO whatever with "192.168.0.2" or "128"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName
    computername    REG_SZ    OWEN-PC

end report FOR 192.168.0.2 ===============================
TTL line found FOR 127.0.0.1 is Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
yourstring is "128"
127.0.0.1 online , TTL: 128
now DO whatever with "127.0.0.1" or "128"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName
    computername    REG_SZ    OWEN-PC

end report FOR 127.0.0.1 ===============================
```

Note: error in the selection of the string after `TTL` corrected - a stray `~` sneaked in (corrected)

I've used a set selection of addresses - you're obviously aware of how to return this to `for /l %%a ...` and how to build `192.168.1.%%a` as required.

I can't test what you appear to want to retrieve from the active machines (computer name?) as I don't have any other machines active. I've just used what came back with a TTL response.

Note `nul` not `null` Using the latter will create a file called `null`.

Note that `for /l` takes 3 parameters - there are 4 on your comment.

The caret is not required (but harmless) in `"delims== "` The characters between the first `=` and the `"` are delimiters - but the space must be last (for future reference) - `"delims="` turns off all delimiters as the delimiter-count is not reliable in this application.

Note also I've removed the redirection to `query_result.txt` to show the results on-screen.

Comment: Thanks... But I am not getting the output of IF condition. I've tried every possible combination (Here in lab the TTL is 128 only). The condition is met. If I print the %%a variable without IF it does, but there is no output after putting an IF there. Otherwise I wouldnt have posted a question.

Comment: Yes sir, you are right. Although the tokens=8 recognises the TTL as 64 and 128 but it doesnt do it in case of "IF" applied to command. I got it now. Thanks alot. But could you please elaborate the use of SET you had used. It seems like regular expressions (like in Linux) but I haven’t learnt it yet. Request you to plz explain it. Also plz give an example of nested FOR and IF loops. A 3 or 4 level nested loops example. U might have discovered the need for it from my post. Also the use of braces '(' ')'. I would be grateful.

Comment: It is still not completely working for me. If I add GEQ alongwith LEQ, it doesn't show up anything:    @echo off
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "yourstring=!yourstring:~*TTL=!"
    set "yourstring=!yourstring:~1!"
    for /l %%a in (1 7 8 100) do for /f "tokens=9 delims=^= " %%b in ('ping -n     1 192.168.1.%%a ^| find /I "TTL"') do if %%b leq 128 if %%b GEQ 65     (echo 192.168.1.%%a online , TTL: %%b)